# Attribute 'min' of input type number works wrong

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input type number with atrributes min,max,step;

In documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/number
says

> The minimum value to accept for this input. If the value of the element is less than this, the element fails constraint validation. If a value is specified for min that isn't a valid number, the input has no minimum value.
>
> This value must be less than or equal to the value of the max attribute.

But in real seems like the min attribute also change basic value of my input,in total that increment value by user input wrong.

You can try this:

Works fine(with no min attribute):https://jsfiddle.net/utqLrveh/7/

Works wrong(with min attribute):https://jsfiddle.net/utqLrveh/6/

Javascript part

```
var e=document.getElementById('basic');
e.setAttribute('value',16);
e.step=32;
e.max=59;
```

HTML part(works wrong with min attribute)

```
<input id="basic" type="number" value="0" min="5">
```

(works fine with no min attribute)

```
<input id="basic" type="number" value="0">
```

With no min the first user increment return 48(value=16+step=32);
With min the first user increment return 37( ̶v̶a̶l̶u̶e̶=̶1̶6̶  min=5+step=32);

Comment: It seems that `value` can't be less than `min`

Comment: For me all working as expected. Can you explain more what kind of functionality you want?

Comment: Just tested it with firefox. It seems the step is always based on the min-value and not the current value, if the min-value is set.

Comment: I think that `value` attribute sets just default value of input, but not initial one. It's valid until user starts change input.

Comment: from [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number#step): min if specified, value otherwise, and an appropriate default value if neither of those is provided

Comment: If min and step specified then first allowed value is min value and other values must be x steps from min value...so 5->37 ...and next is not allowed because of your max value

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this behaviour (in my understanding) is that once you set the `min` value (e.g. `5`), the future values (that will be obtained after the `<input>` was incremented/decremented) would be based on it **regardless of the default `value`**.

In other words, if you set the `value` to say 16 and that the range is [5, 59] with a step of 32, the `<input>` can only get values such that any values `val` that you can obtain in the `<input>` field, you'll have this: `val = input.min + n * input.step` where n is the number of increments from the `input.min` (i.e. the minimum it can take).

So in your case, you'll end up with having a range of values as follows `[5, 37]` (since `69 = 5 + 3 * 32` is above `59` and so are any `5 + 32 * n` where `n >= 3`).